# Jquery script is not reacting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On [this site](http://litebook.eu) i have below jQuery function. But its not reacting?

It should add and remove CSS classes to `<header id="navbar">` after scrolling down 150px.

Does anybody know whats wrong?

```
var fixed = 0;
function toggleNavbar() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > (150)) {
        if (fixed == 0) {
            fixed = 1;
            $("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top").css({opacity: 0,top: -30}).animate({opacity: 1,top: 0}, 200, function() {
            });
            $("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
            $("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeader");
        }
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < (150)) {
        if (fixed == 1) {
            fixed = 0;
            $("#navbar").animate({opacity: 0,top: -30}, 200, function() {
                $("#navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                $("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
                $("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeader").animate({opacity: 1,top: 0}, 300);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is triggering `toggleNavBar()`?

Comment: are you getting error on console ?

Comment: Can you show us line, where you are triggering this function? Are you triggering it on document ready?

Comment: @Beri: He's triggering it here if I'm right: http://litebook.eu/sites/all/themes/litebook/js/fixed-menu-scroll.js?nf85nr

Comment: @FIA2008: No, he is *defining* it there. I couldn't find anywhere where the function is *invoked*.

Comment: problems seems to be related to the $ that is undefined.
trying to put $ in chrome console will output `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (more: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

```
   jQuery( window ).scroll(function() {
      toggleNavbar(); 
   });
```

I don´t know why, but the $ is not defined on your page, using the jQuery reference is working fine.

You might fix your js as well to:

```
var fixed = 0;
function toggleNavbar() {
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (150)) {
        if (fixed == 0) {
            fixed = 1;
            jQuery("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top").css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: -30
            }).animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: 0
            }, 200, function() {});
            jQuery("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
            jQuery("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeader");
        }
    }
    if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() < (150)) {
        if (fixed == 1) {
            fixed = 0;
            jQuery("#navbar").animate({
                opacity: 0,
                top: -30
            }, 200, function() {
                jQuery("#navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                jQuery("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
                jQuery("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeader").animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    top: 0
                }, 300);
            });
        }
    }
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

     toggleNavbar(); 
});
```

Comment: Regarding my original script. On [this site](http://www.montere.it) it's working fine... I try to do exactly the same method because i want the <header> animate from top after scrolling. Thanks

Comment: If i test it on mobile i get a problem. How do i have to fix this?

Comment: What problem do you get?

Comment: You can [test it here](http://litebook.eu) after you resize the screen you will discover the problem. **1)** If you scroll down on mobile the sticky menu appears. It shouldn't appear. **2)** If you click the Hamburger button the menu doesn't collapse in again..? Thanks!

Comment: it should work like on [this site](http://www.montere.it) for example. Less the 772px something happens with the menu and if you scroll down the sticky menu doesn't appear anymore...

Comment: Is there anything you do to avoid this behaviour? E.g. having an window-onresize-event which is disabling this functionality?

Comment: check http://api.jquery.com/resize/ it´s a bit much to be explained in a comment, you might open a new question...

Comment: Ok thanks [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994219/disable-jquery-fading-header-menu-function-after-bootstrap-collapse) i opened a new question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `http://litebook.eu/sites/all/themes/litebook/js/fixed-menu-scroll.js?nf85nr` file:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($) {

    var fixed = 0;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > (150)) {
            if (fixed == 0) {
                fixed = 1;
                $("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top").css({
                    opacity: 0,
                    top: -30
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    top: 0
                }, 200, function() {});
                $("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
                $("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeader");
            }
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < (150)) {
            if (fixed == 1) {
                fixed = 0;
                $("#navbar").animate({
                    opacity: 0,
                    top: -30
                }, 200, function() {
                    $("#navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                    $("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
                    $("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeader").animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        top: 0
                    }, 300);
                });
            }
        }

});
```

Comment: This will do it once. I assume he wants to attach it to the scroll event, not execute it on page load.

Comment: i tried that before but its not working. I am using jQuery 1.7. I already tried 1.10 but no result.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

`navScroller` is called on document ready which in turn binds the scroll event to $(window). `ProcessScroll` is called when you scroll.

```
var APP = APP || {};
APP.header = (function () {

    return {
        navScroller: function() {
            var $win = $(window),
                navTop = 150,
                isFixed = 0;

            processScroll();

            $win.on('scroll', processScroll);

            function processScroll() {
                var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();
                if (scrollTop > navTop && !isFixed) {
                    isFixed = 1;
                    $("#navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top").css({opacity: 0,top: -30}).animate({opacity: 1,top: 0}, 200, function() {});
                    $("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
                    $("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeader");
                } else if (scrollTop < navTop && isFixed) {
                    isFixed = 0;
                    $("#navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
                    $("#navbar").removeClass("websiteHeaderSticky");
                    $("#navbar").addClass("websiteHeader").animate({opacity: 1,top: 0}, 300);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();

$(function () {
    APP.header.navScroller();
});
```

Comment: no it's not working. Regarding my original script. On [this site](http://www.montere.it) it's working fine... I try to do exactly the same method because i want the `<header>` animate from top after scrolling. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/gu531aay/2/

write your function inside `window.scroll`

```
var num = 150;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('#topSmallNav').addClass('showtopbar');
    } else {
        $('#topSmallNav').removeClass('showtopbar');
    }
});
```

```js
    var num = 150;

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('#topSmallNav').addClass('showtopbar');
      } else {
        $('#topSmallNav').removeClass('showtopbar');
      }
    });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#topSmallNav {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
#topSmallNav.showtopbar {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topSmallNav"><a href="#">fafa</a>

</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede</p>
```

Comment: but again also like my original script in console i get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function fixed-menu-scroll.js?nf8asv:3(anonymous function)` What is the problem?

Comment: check with part by part first check if `window.scroll` is working and add the condition which jquery you are using?

Comment: i just added `jQuery(function($){` above and close it with `});`. Than it works!